# Track HTTP responses different than 200 on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, http

Is there a tool (or gem) to track or get a report on all responses given by the application with the status different than 200 without having to implement it manually?

Comment: First question is - why do you need it? Do you need it for the API, or to catch any status different from 200, as it could happen while refreshing a page. So first question is - why do you need it?

Comment: We have an API with a considerable number of requests, and our CTO asked if we could have a control and follow those occurrences, even though I know there could be so many irrelevant cases. @Aleks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a tool or a gem, as this could be easily done by implementing a Rails middle-ware.

As the question is rather generic, then I will answer it in a more generic way. 
Create a middle-ware (you can find a number of resources for this for Rails), then inside a middleware module add line of code something like:

```
status, headers, body = @application.call(request.env)
```

And after that line check what was the status of the response and do whatever you want with that response - record in database, report in Airbrake etc.

Comment: Just a side comment, as I am not too sure how your app is organized, and if your app is not just consisted of an API, maybe keep in mind to check that the API url has been called before checking and logging any responses.